# Code Cleanup Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a variable named `inScreenshotmode` in AppDelegate:

```
#if DEBUG
var inScreenshotMode: Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "abc")
}
#else // Release
let inScreenshotMode = false
#endif
```

So how can I optimise the below code?

```
    let totalValue = appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode == true ? basicInfo.value : configuration.value
```

If I do

```
let totalValue = appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode ? basicInfo.value : configuration.value
```

I getting error:

> **Value of optional type 'Bool?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? Replace 'appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode' with
>   '(appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode)!'**

What is the best solution?

Comment: Why you declaring `appDelegate` as optional?

Comment: extension UIViewController {
    
    weak var appDelegate: AppDelegate? {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    }
}

Comment: extension UIViewController {
    var appDelegate:AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
}

Comment: I think what @AhmadF is hinting at is, that in _that_ specific case you don't need to declare it as an optional, you can safely force unwrap it. If you can not unwrap `UIApplication.shared.delegate` as an `AppDelegate`, then you may have bigger problems in your app :) So, in that case it is OK to force unwrap

Comment: Use this for your extension, you can force unwrap your appDelegate.

Comment: @pbodsk I hope my answer describes it :)

Comment: @AhmadF it does :) nice answer, nice solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode` is indeed an optional which means that it can return `nil`. Since `nil` is **Equatable**, the part `appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode == true` will always return either `true` or `false`. But using `appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode` on its own can return `true`, `false`, or `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your declaration for `appDelegate` it seems that you are declaring it as an optional (not sure what's the reason of this), what are you facing is called *[Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)*:

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties,
>   methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil. If
>   the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call
>   succeeds; if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript
>   call returns nil. Multiple queries can be chained together, and the
>   entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.

Which means that you have to make sure that `appDelegate` is not `nil` instead of `(appDelegate?.inScreenshotMode)!`, I would recommend to do optional binding:

```
if let unwrappedAppDelegate = appDelegate {
    let totalValue = unwrappedAppDelegate.inScreenshotMode ? basicInfo.value : configuration.value
}
```